# MS Access hide field name if null value in web page

Tags: ms-access, html

I want to hide or not show Field Names if value is Null, for fields "Location" and "Bin" when updating my eBay webpage Custom Label Fields.
Tried

```
 If IsNull(Me!Location) Then
 Me!Location.Visible = False
 Else
 Me!Location = True
```

but keep getting errors (Method or data not found or runtime 438)  with the following code.

```
Call IE.Document.getElementById("editpane_skuNumber").setAttribute("value", ([CustomLabelCombine]) & "   " & ("Location" & "   " & [Location]) & "    " & ("Bin" & " " & [Bin]))
```

If you have a better solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Is IE.Document.GetelementsbyID a subroutine or function? if not, remove the word "call" and replace with

```
me.Location = IE.Document.getElementById("editpane_skuNumber").setAttribute("value", ([CustomLabelCombine]) & "   " & ("Location" & "   " & [Location]) & "    " & ("Bin" & " " & [Bin]))
If IsNull(Me!Location) Then
Me!Location.Visible = False
Else
Me!Location = True
End IF
```

Comment1:

When using "Call" you are asking the current procedure to "Call" a public subroutine. Example below

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()
Call TestRoutine
End Sub

Public Sub TestRoutine()
Msgbox "You clicked Button 1"
End Sub
```

If you aren't calling another subroutine to execute more coding, then remove the word "Call".

I also noticed your if is missing the .visible after the else for line

```
Me!Location = true
```

Should be:

```
Me!Location.Visible = true
```

Comment: It's a subroutine.  Got a runtime 438 error.  I realized after posting that I have "Location" in quotes in my Call may be an issue.  Would that force Access to display Location even with no value/null no matter what I do?   Chris, Thank You for taking time with my question- Bill

Comment: What I meant by "Is IE.Document.GetElementByID a subroutine or function?" is when using the word "Call", you are telling your application to call a public sub routine in your modules. I have edited my answer to show the example to this comment.